# Compare Color and Format of 2 files in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I'm currently working on a macro to compare 2 big files that should be identical.
The point of the macro is to find if their is differences concening the color, the formula or the format between the files. I've made one that compare cell by cell but the run takes 5 hours...

I've tried the use of variant but I only managed to compare the value.

Here is the part of the code were I would like to add the Interior.ColorIndex and .Format:

```
For colonne = 1 To dercolonne
For ligne = 1 To derligne
Windows(WB_1).Activate
Sheets(wsname).Activate
MontabA = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(derligne, dercolonne)).FormulaR1C1Local
contenue1 = MontabA(ligne, colonne)
If Err > 0 Then
erreur = erreur & sh.Name & " " & Cells(ligne, colonne).Address & ": erreur cellule" & vbCrLf
End If
Windows(WB_2).Activate
Sheets(wsname).Activate
MontabB = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(derligne, dercolonne)).FormulaR1C1Local
contenue2 = MontabB(ligne, colonne)
If contenue1 <> contenue2 Then
erreur = erreur & sh.Name & ": " & Cells(derligne, dercolonne).Address & vbCrLf
Else
End If
Next ligne
Next colonne
```

Many thanks,

Quentin

Comment: Just to throw it out there - if you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use the [Inquire add-in](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42) to compare files...

Comment: You don't need to select/activate anything here - declare two worksheet variables and use those to qualify all your Range/Cells calls.  And *please* indent your code when posting.  You're doing this `MontabA = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(derligne, dercolonne)).FormulaR1C1Local` *every time* through your loop - move that before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be faster but it really depends on how many comparisons you need to make, and to what level of detail.

```
Dim ws1, ws2, c1, c2

Set ws1 = Workbooks(WB_1).Sheets(wsname)
Set ws2 = Workbooks(WB_2).Sheets(wsname)

MontabA = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(derligne, dercolonne)).FormulaR1C1Local
MontabB = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(derligne, dercolonne)).FormulaR1C1Local

For colonne = 1 To dercolonne
    For ligne = 1 To derligne

        Set c1 = ws1.Cells(ligne, colonne)
        Set c2 = ws2.Cells(ligne, colonne)

        If MontabA(ligne, colonne) <> MontabA(ligne, colonne) Then
            'add content error
        End If

        If c1.Interior.Color <> c2.Interior.Color Then
            'add color error
        End If

        'etc other tests here

    Next ligne
Next colonne
```

Comment: Thank you! You just reduced the process time by 300 (litteraly)!